# JQuery-Mobile and ASP.Net - AJAX or Postback?

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile

I've been developing ASP.Net for the past and until recently come across a mobile project. Jquery-Mobile seems perfect as a framework for this, so I just dived into it.

Currently I'm using ASP.Net approach to put server controls on a page, then use jqm to enhance those controls to make them looks mobile. I actually do postback to collect form data and process them in code-behind.
To avoid a full page refresh, I had to mix them with updatepanel too. Somehow I got them working but deep down I just feel this isn't the right way (or efficient way) of doing it.

There's too much complication of mixing things up to get them right, so I think maybe I should just avoid postback and do everything-else in pure AJAX requests?

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
  url: "/GetName",
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"

})
.success(function (response) {
  alert(response);
});
```

Code-behind:

```
[WebMethod ()] 
public String GetName()
{ return "Jack"; }
```

Questions:

- This works, but is this the better way to go with jQuery-Mobile websites, or this is just another bad example?
- Is UpdatePanel and postback a bad idea for this scenario? (I know they work)
- If AJAX is preferred, how do I go about populating a dropdownlist on pageload (Not server control)? Sending an AJAX request to populate dropdownlist on $(document).ready() seems stupid to me

What I'm looking for is rules of thumb of developing a mobile site, I don't want to steer too far away from what should be doing right. Your inputs are very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just an advice for people who trying to make the same mistake like I did, JQM really doesn't go along with WebForm. Period. You might get it to work somehow, but the result and effort just not worth it (the  whole experience is plain awful!). Use combination like HTML5/JQ/JQM/CSS3, RequireJS, BackboneJS, Handlebars, Phonegap etc, they are much better choice for developing mobile application. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

asp.net Web Forms and jQuery Mobile really don't work together. The postback model breaks the way that jQuery Mobile ajax works and it will fall appart when you have more than a single page or form. Specifically Web Forms requires a single `<form>` tag that wraps all server side controls and you cannot introduce additional "internal" forms. jQuery Mobile really works best with the ajax model and one or more "pages" (`<div data-role="page">`) and forms that are contained within the DOM. Update panels will ultimately cause chaos.

One approach is to simply turn off jQuery Mobile ajax loading. You can do that with this:

```
//note that the order of script loading here is critical.
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).bind(“mobileinit”, function() {
        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    });
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js">
</script>
```

but in the end, you won't have a highly efficient web site. If you site is running over a local wireless network, it may be good enough.

I work in a mostly Web Forms environment and had a need for a Web Forms based jQuery Mobile app and coded 5 or so "pages" as a single static html file. I then relied on JavaScript and jQuery ajax loading to ASMX web service end points. I also made extensive use of KnockoutJS but I certainly could have relied solely of JavaScript and jQuery ajax to pull data (and in my case, the app was of a reporting nature with no data updating.) If you are saving data, you can use the same technique.

An even better approach is to go with asp.net MVC which eliminates the forced postback model and allows fine grained control over where your `<form>` tags are placed.

I am working on a larger mobile site and using MVC for the back end and taking full advantage of Razor views but in the end, I am relying on client side ajax calls for all data and KnockoutJS for almost all dynamic markup. In the end, my client side app isn't all that different between Web Forms and MVC. MVC based controllers are easier to work with for ajax end points and the solution is cleaner.

In general, I would lump both solutions into the "single page application" aka SPA approach. There are other approaches that might work with Web Forms but in my limited exploration, this was the best option.

Comment: This is exactly how I handle these situations too. Use jQM with MVC, and knockout if you have a heavy amount of data on a page.

Comment: Fair answer. But I don't see company moving to embrace MVC in short time. We had to stick with webforms for now. Can you suggest how one should populate the jqm select-menu in webform on pageload?

Comment: You have a couple of options: 1. You could modify the markup using traditional Web Form controls `<asp:DropDownList>` etc. You will need to insure you turn off jQuery Mobile ajax loading as I detailed before and your site should work fine. If you are expecting external, 3G clients to connect to this type of site, they will likely have disappointing experiences. You may also need to insure unique URLs across certain linking and postbacks. Some mobile browsers can be very aggressive with their caching. I know there are rules as to how and when but I don't know what they are.

Comment: The second option is to go with the static markup approach and use JavaScript and ajax loading for your `<select>` `<option>` items. The most popular approach is to use jQuery (core) and some simple looping to append items to the DOM. If your project / app gets large, you will need to rely on a templating engine and some type of   client data binding library or framework. There are a number of them and I have chosen to work with KnockoutJS.

Comment: I think the basic dilemma that you and your company face is that fundamentally, building mobile web apps requires a very different approach compared to building web apps for traditional desktops. jQuery Mobile does a nice job getting you most of the way there and there are certainly trade offs between native and cross platform web. Building on top of Web Forms just makes all of this so much more difficult. You may not be ready to embrace MVC but Web Forms may not get you where you want to go.